# data.table incorrect behaviour on PowerPC and SPARC (both big-endian)

Tags: r, data.table

There is a data.table `dt`, where I did some classification using `cut`:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(x = rnorm(10))
dt[, y := cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, 0, Inf), labels = 1:2)]
```

If I convert the resulting factor `y` to numeric values (using a function `as.Numeric` based on `?factor`), the binary search doesn't work any more, although `z` is numeric.

```
as.Numeric <- function(f){
  as.numeric(levels(f))[f]
}

dt[, z := as.Numeric(y)] # as.numeric(as.character(y))
                                    # is working ...
dt
##              x y z
##  1: -0.6264538 1 1
##  2:  0.1836433 2 2
##  3: -0.8356286 1 1
##  4:  1.5952808 2 2
##  5:  0.3295078 2 2
##  6: -0.8204684 1 1
##  7:  0.4874291 2 2
##  8:  0.7383247 2 2
##  9:  0.5757814 2 2
## 10: -0.3053884 1 1

setkey(dt, z)
dt
##              x y z
##  1:  0.1836433 2 2
##  2:  1.5952808 2 2
##  3:  0.3295078 2 2
##  4:  0.4874291 2 2
##  5:  0.7383247 2 2
##  6:  0.5757814 2 2
##  7: -0.6264538 1 1
##  8: -0.8356286 1 1
##  9: -0.8204684 1 1
## 10: -0.3053884 1 1

dt[J(1)] # doesn't work
##     x  y z
## 1: NA NA 1

dt[y == 1, ] # works fine
##             x y z
## 1: -0.6264538 1 1
## 2: -0.8356286 1 1
## 3: -0.8204684 1 1
## 4: -0.3053884 1 1

str(dt)
## Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
##  $ x: num  0.184 1.595 0.33 0.487 0.738 ...
##  $ y: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1
##  $ z: num  2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1
##  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
##  - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "z"
```

Try to set the key again, didn't help:

```
setkey(dt, z)
## Warning message:
## In setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose) :
##   Already keyed by this key but had invalid row order, key rebuilt. If you didn't go under the hood please let datatable-help know so the root cause can be fixed.

dt
##              x y z
##  1:  0.1836433 2 2
##  2:  1.5952808 2 2
##  3:  0.3295078 2 2
##  4:  0.4874291 2 2
##  5:  0.7383247 2 2
##  6:  0.5757814 2 2
##  7: -0.6264538 1 1
##  8: -0.8356286 1 1
##  9: -0.8204684 1 1
## 10: -0.3053884 1 1

dt[J(1)] # doesn't work
##     x  y z
## 1: NA NA 1
```

A *vector scan* is working, because the key is not needed. Using `as.numeric(as.character(y))` is also working. Maybe the `[`-operator in `as.Numeric` is a problem? Using the same code with dt 1.8.10 everything is like expected. It was not so easy to find out, why the code is not working in 1.9.3 any more ...

### Question:

Is this a bug?

p.s.:

```
sessionInfo()
## R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
## Platform: powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

## locale:
##  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
##  [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
##  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
##  [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
##  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
## [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

## attached base packages:
## [1] splines   grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
## [8] methods   base     

## other attached packages:
##  [1] plyr_1.8.1        reshape2_1.4      lubridate_1.3.3   HP14int_0.1-15   
##  [5] Hmisc_3.14-4      Formula_1.1-1     survival_2.37-7   lattice_0.20-29  
##  [9] HP14unidata_1.1-1 data.table_1.9.3 

## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
## [1] cluster_1.15.2      digest_0.6.4        latticeExtra_0.6-26
## [4] memoise_0.2.1       RColorBrewer_1.0-5  Rcpp_0.11.1        
## [7] stringr_0.6.2       tools_3.1.0

writeLines(paste("Endianess:", .Platform$endian))
## Endianess: big
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not able to reproduce it. Tested with 1.9.3 on R v3.0.3 and v3.1.0, OS X Mountain Lion and works fine. I see that `z` is sorted in descending order from your `str` output. So it's clear why it's not working (continued)...

Comment: I'll have to ask you a couple of things off the top of my head. 1) Could you please paste the error numbers, if any, from running `test.data.table()`? What happens with `1.9.2 + R v3.1.0` and `1.9.3 + R v3.0.3`? 3) Also, could you paste `dt` after running `setkey(dt, z)` (including warning messages, if any) twice? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it's in the wrong order. I added `dt` after `setkey(dt, z)` now in the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now fixed in [v1.9.5 on GitHub](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki). Thanks for reporting.

> Compatibility with big endian machines (e.g., SPARC and PowerPC) is restored. Most Windows, Linux and Mac systems are little endian; type `.Platform$endian` to confirm. Thanks to Gerhard Nachtmann for reporting and the [QEMU project](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) for their PowerPC emulator.

Comment: It's working in 1.9.5 again. Thanks 
[@Matt](http://stackoverflow.com/users/403310/matt-dowle)! See also http://github.com/nachti/datatable_test